# Long click method in Appium, Python

Tags: python, appium, long-click

Is there any long click method in Appium on Python?
I need to long click on the area in my program.

```
  def testDevice1(self):

   password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.e.eas.android:id/password')
   password.send_keys('111111')
   time.sleep(5)
   password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.e.eas.android:id/password').longClick()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Python) look up TouchAction. you can string commands together:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
ta = TouchAction(driver)
ta.press(x=x, y=y).release().perform()

# some_web_obj = driver.find...
ta.press(some_web_obj).wait(duration_in_millisec).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction

actions = TouchAction(driver)
actions.long_press(element, duration=press_duration_in_ms)
actions.perform()
```

For more information https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/commands/interactions/touch/long-press/

Comment: Agree its mentioned well documented on many sites but doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution** with:
Python 3.x, Appium 1.22.3, Mac M1

- *Long press* on iOS can be achieve using snippet

> **TouchAction(driver).long_press(element).release().perform()**